# Can I have separate front-end layers for iOS and Android using React Native

Tags: react-native, frontend, user-experience

Is it possible to develop an app using React Native that have a very distinct UI/UX in iOS vs Android while at the same time achieving a common business layer to manage API's, local data, etc.? The goal would be to provide a look & feel that maximizes the design guidelines from Apple and Google so users get the most native experience from each ecosystem. I know it is possible to write code that is specific to each platform (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/platform-specific-code.html) but all the example apps that I've seen have the same look and feel so it's hard to know if this approach is really feasible or if for major differences it doesn't make sense because it ends up in too much duplicate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Things to note**

- Business logic will be on containers.
- Components/Views will be have props and callbacks to process data from containers.
- Use a feature based architecture.
- Avoid using life cycle methods in classes where it's not needed.

You can follow the smart /dumb component architecture where the smart containers deals with the business logic while the dumb ones takes care of presentation.

Follow : http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

You can separate the containers as container.js and containerview.js for better separation.

Follow Dan's [Presentational Components](https://www.fullstackreact.com/p/using-presentational-and-container-components-with-redux/)

For iOS and Android separation u can use index.ios.js and index.android.js in each folder where each one is a view component.

Additional info on [smart/dumb Components](https://jaketrent.com/post/smart-dumb-components-react/)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can define different components for ios and android. For eg:

   ```
   ExampleComponent.android.js 
   ExampleComponent.ios.js
   ```

   then import them in your view as

   ```
   import ExampleComponent from './ExampleComponent';
   ```
2. Or else inside view you can check the platform and render different UIs. For eg:

   render(){
       return(
                   
       {Platform.OS === 'android' ? for android UI}
       {Platform.OS === 'ios' ? for ios UI}
                   
      );
   }

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally render some elements in react-native based on whichever platform the app is running on. Id recommend following the link you provided, but a super simple way would be to do something like this

```
render(){
    if(Platform.OS === 'android'){
        return(
           <View><Text>Android</Text></View>
        )
    };

    if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){
        return(
           <View><Text>IOS</Text></View>
        )
    };
}
```

Occassionally i use this method if i want to follow platform specific design guidelines, for example different looking buttons and/or text. Or even lower level things like color, shadow offset and fonts.

I'd only use this on very low level components however, as over-using it could lead to alot of duplicate code. Haven't done this for navigation as of yet, and i assume this is what you are asking the question for.